# How to split a string by delimter ";" to rows without using STRING_SPLIT function

Tags: sql, split

I would like to know if there are any other alternative to splitting a string by its ";" delimiter into separate rows without using the STRING_SPLIT function or CREATE or WITH.

The original data looks as follows:

```
ID       STRING
1        a;b;c
2        e;f
3        e;f;g;h
```

And I would like to see it in this form:

```
ID       STRING
1        a
1        b
1        c
2        e
2        f
3        e
3        f
3        g
3        h
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and the SQL client being used is irrelevant here). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using (Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, ...) [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: The original data looks as follows:

ID    STRING                                                                                                                           1       a;b;c 
2       e;f
3       e;f;g;h

And I would like to see it in this form:

ID   STRING                                                                                                                           1        a
1        b
1        c
2        e
2        f
3        e
3        f
3        g
3        h

Comment: I'm using SQL Workbench/J

Comment: That is a SQL client tool that can connect to many different database products. It's totally irrelevant for this question

Comment: If you want to work with the separate values in the database, then they should not be stored as as csv in there in the first place. So, the obvious way would be to do this outside SQL. Write a programm, read the data from the database, use a loop, write the better data into the database.

Answer (score 0):

FOR SQL SERVER you can use this or try similar queries as you didn't specified database name.

```sql
REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(STRING), ',', '.'), 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

The classic approach uses a cross join to reference each individual character in the string:

```
select
    substring(strings,
        d0.n + d1.n * 10 + 1,
        charindex(';', strings + ';', d0.n + d1.n * 10 + 1) - (d0.n + d1.n * 10 + 1))
from s cross join (
    select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
    select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all
    select 8 union all select 9
) d0(n) cross join (
    select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
    select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all
    select 8 union all select 9
) d1(n)
where substring(';' + strings, d0.n + d1.n * 10 + 1, 1) = ';'
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f32cbc2fd9a4b78b802dafe9044e786e

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT id,value AS string
  FROM yourtable
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(string, ';')
```

Without using create, with or string_split function in Sql Server one way to achived this is:

```
SELECT  ID, SUBSTRING(STRING + ';', number, CHARINDEX(';', STRING + ';', number) - number) AS STRING
FROM your_table
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (LEN(STRING) + 1) 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS number
    FROM 
        master..spt_values
) AS Numbers
WHERE SUBSTRING(';' + STRING, number, 1) = ';'
    AND LEN(SUBSTRING( STRING + ';', number, CHARINDEX(';', STRING + ';', number) - number)) > 0
ORDER BY ID, number;
```

Hope it helps.